# Extract specific data from string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to capture multiple string which match some specific patterns,
For example my string is like

```
String textData = "#1_Label for UK#2_Label for US#4_Label for FR#";
```

I want to get string between two # which match with string like for `UK`

Output should like this 
if match string is `UK` than 
    output should be `1_Label for UK`
if match string is `label` than
    output should be `1_Label for UK, 2_Label for US` and `4_Label for FR`
if match string is `1_` than
    output should be `1_Label for UK`

I don't want to extract data via array list and extraction should be case insensitive.

Can you please help me out from this problem?

Regards,
Ashish Mishra

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "if match string is `UK`/`label`/`1_`". From what I can see you input-string has all three of those strings in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data always is between two hashes, try a regex like this: `(?i)#.*your_match.*#` where `your_match` would be `UK`, `label`, `1_` etc.

Then use this expression in conjunction with the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

If you want to match multiple strings, you'd need to exclude the hashes from the match by using look-around methods as well as reluctant modifiers, e.g. `(?i)(?<=#).*?label.*?(?=#)`.

Short breakdown:

- `(?i)` will make the expression case insensitive
- `(?<=#)` is a positive look-behind, i.e. the match must be preceeded by a hash (but doesn't include the hash)
- `.*?` matches any sequence of characters but is reluctant, i.e. it tries to match as few characters as possible
- `(?=#)` is a positive look-ahead, which means the match must be followed by a hash (also not included in the match)

Without the look-around methods the hashes would be included in the match and thus using `Matcher.find()` you'd skip every other label in your test string, i.e. you'd get the matches `#1_Label for UK#` and `#4_Label for FR#` but not `#2_Label for US#`.

Without the relucatant modifiers the expression would match everything between the first and the last hash.

As an alternative and better, replace `.*?` with `[^#]*`, which would mean that the match cannot contain any hash, thus removing the need for reluctant modifiers as well as removing the problem that looking for `US` would match `1_Label for UK#2_Label for US`.

So most probably the final regex you're after looks like this: `(?i)(?<=#)[^#]*your_match[^#]*(?=#)`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for search:

```
#([^#]*?Label[^#]*)(?=#)
```

Replace `Label` with your search keyword.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kQ0zR5/1)

**Java Pattern:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "#([^#]*?" + Pattern.quote(keyword) + "[^#]*)(?=#)" );
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for your quick reply

Answer (score 1):

```
([^#]*UK[^#]*)   for UK

([^#]*Label[^#]*) for Label

([^#]*1_[^#]*)    for 1_
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kQ0zR5/3

http://regex101.com/r/kQ0zR5/4

http://regex101.com/r/kQ0zR5/5

Comment: Thanks VKS for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with below pattern,

```
(?i)([^#]*?us[^#]*)(?=#)
```

Thank you so much Anubhava, VKS and Thomas for you reply.

Regards,
Ashish Mishra

Comment: This was precisely my answer also. Better not to post it as an answer and vote up / accept the answers that work for you.